# How to merge/combining multiple Object into Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, arrayobject

im looking best way to merge object into array..
this my issue :

```
Object {
  "payload": Array [
    Object {
      "category": "kontrakan",
    },
    Object {
      "Tenant": "anji",
    },
  ],
  "type": "GET_DATA_VENUE_SUCCESS",
}

Object {
  "payload": Array [
    Object {
      "category": "kost",
    },
    Object {
      "Tenant": "ade",
    },
  ],
  "type": "GET_DATA_VENUE_SUCCESS",
}
```

expect transform like this :

```
{
  [
   {"category" : "kontrakan","Tenant" : "anji"}, 
   {"category" : "kost", "Tenant" : "ade"}
  ]
}
```

here code :

```
let obj = doc.data();
let arrObj = _.map(_.keys(obj), key => ({ [key]: obj[key] }));
console.log(arrObj);
```

im was already try with another solutions. object.assign/key, lodash : _.merge, union still not working perfectly...

Comment: I'm totally lost, can you explain where the A, B, Fizz and Fuzz are coming from?

Comment: Hi, can you provide input data example?

Comment: The value A,B and FIzz Fuzz is just example value , i'll edit it

Comment: Also, the desired output is not valid.

Comment: What syntax does the original objects derive from?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map` method in combination with `reduce` and `Object.assign` for merging `objects` *properties*.

```js
var arr = [{ "payload": [ { "category": "kontrakan", }, { "Tenant": "anji", } ], "type": "GET_DATA_VENUE_SUCCESS", }, { "payload": [ { "category": "kost", }, { "Tenant": "ade", }, ], "type": "GET_DATA_VENUE_SUCCESS", }]

var result = arr.map(({payload}) => payload.reduce((obj, item) => Object.assign(obj, item), {}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is [reduce](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp).

You can use reduce to combine the 'payload' data into a single object. By using a object as the accumulator.

Example:

```
const a = {
  payload: [{
    category: 'a'
  },
  {
    tenant: 'a'
  }]
};


function mergePayload(obj) {
  return obj.payload.reduce((newObj, payloadObj) => {
    // Create a new object with the properties of the old and the new combined
    return Object.assign(newObj, payloadObj);
  }, {});
}

// {category: "a", tenant: "a"}
console.log(mergePayload(a))
```

You can map an array with data to the reducer:

```
const data = [a, a];

// [{category: "a", tenant: "a"}, {category: "a", tenant: "a"}]
console.log(data.map((d) => mergePayload(d)));
```

Edit:
You can make the reduce shorter, but this would no longer make room for the comment.

```
function mergePayload(obj) {
  return obj.payload.reduce((newObj, payloadObj) => Object.assign(newObj, payloadObj), {})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only two objects into the array and the possible properties are "category" and "Tenant"

```js
let arr = [{  "payload": [{      "category": "kontrakan",    },    {      "Tenant": "anji",    },  ],  "type": "GET_DATA_VENUE_SUCCESS"}, {  "payload": [{      "category": "kost",    },    {      "Tenant": "ade",    },  ],  "type": "GET_DATA_VENUE_SUCCESS"}],
    result = arr.map(({payload: [{category: category}, {Tenant: tenant}]}) => ({category, tenant}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```